# difference in jQuery object context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to obtain some insight in the context of a jQuery object. I've read a ton of questions on SO, but they all want to fix a specific problem, and the answers thus fix the problem, and didn't really provide me with the knowledge I'm hoping for.

So I have two buttons, and I have a click event that listens for both of them like so:

```
$('#copyRI, #copyIR').click(function () {...}
```

Now when I try to establish which element was clicked like so:

```
$('#copyRI, #copyIR').click(function () {
    var test = $(this);
    var test2 = $('#copyIR');
    var compare = (test === test2);
  }
```

`compare` returns false when I click the button with id = `#copyIR` 
when debugging I noticed that the context of `test` and `test2` are different:
[image: jquery object context difference]

Now I'm not looking for a way to successfully establish which button was clicked, but I want to obtain some insight in the concept of the "context" in a jQuery object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `$(this)` you create a new jQuery object, instantiating it with an HTML Element.

When you call `$('#copyIR')` you create a new jQuery object, instantiating it with a selector. This stores extra information in the object, including the selector itself.

Even if that wasn't the case, you would be creating two different objects and `===` (and `==` for that matter) test if two objects are *the same object* not if they are *identical* objects.

`$(this) === $(this)` would also return false.

If you want to test if the elements are the same, then you can compare the underlying DOM nodes (since those will be the same object)

```
var compare = (test[0] === test2[0]);
```

Alternatively, you can just test if the object you have in the first place matches the selector:

```
var compare = test.is('#copyIR');
```

Comment: Okay, did not realize they were both different instances..
I already went with the `.is()` method, but also wanted to know why the context differed, so thanks for the insight, it really helped my understanding of jQuery!

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** method here.

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

**CODE:**

```
$('#copyRI, #copyIR').click(function () {
  var test = $(this);
  var compare = test.is('#copyIR')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery contexts (being an `Object`) are compared by reference, so `test === test2` would obviously return `false` since each variable is pointing to a different jQuery context (the fact that both contexts internally contains a reference to same DOM object doesn't matter).

Try `is()` instead:

```
var compare = $(this).is('#copyIR');
```

See [Documetnation](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply compare the id.

```
$('#copyRI, #copyIR').click(function () {
  if (this.id === 'copyIR') {
    // do something
  }
}
```